# Is The Good Place inspired by Swedenborg as a state of spirit rather than a Place?

Tags: analysis, book-adaptation, reception, the-good-place

[The Good Place](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4955642/) goes under the premise that four people died and are in the afterlife. In different seasons it is hinted or explicitly said that everything in The Good Place *as a place* is:

> actually the Bad Place.

However ... Maybe The Good Place (or The Bad Place) are not Places, but rather states of spirit. Each of the characters go through spiritual/moral changes (even growth!). Can a spirit's afterlife depend on their intelligence? Nothing should indicate in that path. Can a spiritual character move forward or backwards (or sideways) depending on their actions and frame of mind/heart? This is likely, and even indicated during the story. Hence, the chance that Places are not places, but rather frames of spirit/heart.

If anything, a simple spirit such as Jason is like a happy-go-lucky [golden retriever](http://bojackhorseman.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._Peanutbutter). There may not be much reason to think that because of being stupid should be a reason to go to the Bad Place. Jason is basically a simple and happy person that sometimes makes mistakes out of ignorance, not much bad intent, somewhat childish and searching the world when he steals (and dies in a safe) or ruins the tires of opposing dance crew.

Heaven/Hell as state of spirit is hinted by the mystic [Emanuel Swedenborg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emanuel_Swedenborg). In this author's view, Heaven or Hell are not places where you go after dead but rather the continuation of the way you act, feel and sense in a general spiritual way of dealing with the universe. In this manner, the spirit stays in the state with which it feels best at: good spirits feel at ease in heaven whilst not at ease in the counterpart dimension; and bad spirits by the same opposite coin. So transitions between places are infrequent, but not impossible.

> [*It can never be said that heaven is outside anyone. It is within*](http://www.spiritualwisdom.org.uk/words-of-wisdom.htm)

Michael, the person in charge of the four humans, on a occasion explains to Jason [[S02E02 Dance Dance Resolution](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6949036/?ref_=ttep_ep2)] what the current place is. Even so, after some conversation, Jason concludes, in the scenario of a gorgeous garden: "I give good advice. Guess that's why I'm in the good place".

[image: Jason feels in The Good Place almost all the time, if not always.]

Comment: Side note: Jason has a truly special frame of mind. He actually hits the ball out of the park many many times. A list should even be in order. In S04E4 -_Tinker, Tailor, Demon, Spy_- he discovers an undercover bad Janet. Also, he is the second after Eleanor to regularly realize he is part of an elaborated prank.

Comment: In the following chapter, Jason states that he is not afraid of a billion enemies. A truly free, wild, and happy spirit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be one of several influences, but it is not the main or only influence, as the creator Michael Schur explains to [The Hollywood Reporter](https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/live-feed/good-place-religion-explained-mike-schur-interview-927402), after doing extensive research, he quite because he realized his viewpoint was not limited to specific Religion(s) (Swedonborgism was inspired by Emanuel Swedenborg, a Lutheran Christian Theologian), but he was more interested in the depiction of ethical behavior.

> **“It is very important to make clear in the first 30 seconds of the
>   pilot, this is not one religion’s concept of the afterlife,”** Schur
>   tells The Hollywood Reporter. “I did a lot of research.”
>
> After perusing various theological studies and treatises on holy
>   documents, “**I stopped doing research because I realized it’s about
>   versions of ethical behavior, not religious salvation,"** he says. "The
>   show isn’t taking a side, the people who are there are from every
>   country and religion.”
>
> In fact, **the pilot goes out of its way to demonstrate a United Nations
>   of characters and belief systems**. The idea, Schur says, is that **“not
>   only Christians from Europe can make it to heaven.”**

The article continues to quote Schur and give examples such as dialogue to make his point.